# What is the way to use the one query result in where clause in laravel like we do in sql query using where in clause?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder, laravel-5.8

I'm writing query in Laravel but its giving me error Saying

> ErrorException: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

```php
$subject_ids = DB::table('question_sets')
                   ->select('subject_id')
                   ->where('test_section_id','=',$testDetail->test_section_id)
                   ->distinct()
                   ->get();

$topic_ids = DB::table('topics')
                 ->select('id')
                 ->where('subject_id','=',$subject_ids)
                 ->get();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In below query

```
$subject_ids = DB::table('question_sets')
                   ->select('subject_id')
                   ->where('test_section_id','=',$testDetail->test_section_id)
                   ->distinct()->get();
```

You are getting a collection, if you want a particular value, you can use `first()`
and then you can do

```
$subject_id = DB::table('question_sets')
                  ->select('subject_id')
                  ->where('test_section_id','=',$testDetail->test_section_id)
                  ->distinct()
                  ->pluck('name')
                  ->first();
```

and

```
$topic_ids = DB::table('topics')
                 ->select('id')
                 ->where('subject_id','=',$subject_id)
                 ->get();
```

**or** if you want to match with all $subject_ids, you should use `toArray()` and `whereIn` like

```
$subject_ids = DB::table('question_sets')
                   ->select('subject_id')
                   ->where('test_section_id','=',$testDetail->test_section_id)
                   ->distinct()
                   ->pluck('subject_id')
                   ->toArray();
```

and

```
$topic_ids = DB::table('topics')
                 ->select('id')
                 ->whereIn('subject_id', $subject_ids)
                 ->get();
```

Comment: @yogesh I am glad, I could help you.